# Java FX TableView not editable with FXML

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx-2, tableview

I am currently developing a Java FX Application that includes a `TableView`. In this `TableView` I want to use an editable `CheckBoxTableCell`.
First I had all components added in the Java Code using MiG Layout. With that configuration everything was editable (size of columns, order of columns, checkbox). When I transferred all the code to FXML using Scene Builder everything worked fine except the TableView. I could not figure out how to set the CellFactory and the CellValueFactory in the FXML file (I've seen a couple of examples, but couldn't get it to work). So I decided to set those factories in the `initialize()` method:

```
voteCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<DataItem, Boolean>,     ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(
                CellDataFeatures<DataItem, Boolean> arg0) {
            return arg0.getValue().voteProperty();
        }

    });

voteCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<DataItem, Boolean>, TableCell<DataItem, Boolean>>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell<DataItem, Boolean> call(
                TableColumn<DataItem, Boolean> arg0) {
            return new CheckBoxTableCell<DataItem, Boolean>();
        }

    });

voteCol.setEditable(true);
dataTableView.setEditable(true);
```

Here is the FXML Code generated by Scene Builder

```
<TableView fx:id="dataTableView" editable="true"
        mouseTransparent="true" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="-1.0"
        prefWidth="-1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="41.0"
        AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0"
        AnchorPane.topAnchor="80.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="voteCol" maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0"
                prefWidth="32.0" text="Vote" visible="true" />
            ...
        </columns>
        <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
        </columnResizePolicy>
    </TableView>
```

The databinding with the DataItem is working correctly.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Make sure your that your controller stated in fxml file, controller implements Initializable, voteCol is marked with @FXML

Comment: I did not implement Initializable, thanks! But which initialize-method do I need to use for what code? (There are the @FXML ' initialize()'  and 'initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)'

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your initialization is never called.

Make sure your Controller implements `Initializable` interface and `initialize()` method has correct signature:

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, Resources resources) {
       //....
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried that, but got no better result. The function gets called, because the bindings set in this function work. Although the binding worked before as well